# Loading BaseLayer with Leaflet from ArcGIS REST

Tags: leaflet, arcgis-rest-api

Can someone explain why the second layer isn't working?

The page is loading, but the Mosaic shows up blank.  I'm new to the world of GIS so I don't know exactly what's different between these two MapServers.

The request URL is returning a 404 error so leaflet is not asking the server for the correct tile.  Here is an example a url with the error. https://services.wvgis.wvu.edu/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery_BaseMaps_EarthCover/wv_imagery_WVGISTC_leaf_off_mosaic/MapServer/tile/2/393/279

**Working**:

`https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer`

**Broken**:

`https://services.wvgis.wvu.edu/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery_BaseMaps_EarthCover/wv_imagery_WVGISTC_leaf_off_mosaic/MapServer`

```
var base_layers = {
  "Physical Map": L.esri.tiledMapLayer({
    url: "//server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer",
    maxZoom: 19,
  }),
  "Mosaic": L.esri.tiledMapLayer({
    url: "//services.wvgis.wvu.edu/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery_BaseMaps_EarthCover/wv_imagery_WVGISTC_leaf_off_mosaic/MapServer",
    maxZoom: 18,
  }),
};
```

Comment: Any errors in the browser debugger console or network section?

Comment: @TomazicM I added some info above.

Comment: If you look at the layer through ArcGIS viewer https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?url=https%3A%2F%2Fservices.wvgis.wvu.edu%2Farcgis%2Frest%2Fservices%2FImagery_BaseMaps_EarthCover%2Fwv_imagery_WVGISTC_leaf_off_mosaic%2FMapServer&source=sd and inspect network requests, you'll see that this layer displays tiles at zoom level 0 when base HillShade layer has zoom level 8. It looks like `L.esri` plugin can't handle this.